# Unable to center the Title Tags on Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, centering

I was trying to align images and their post titles centered but somehow the left part of the image and the title gets cut off by a small margin. I tried many things but couldn't get to center the title tags. 
[Here is the site](http://gk-hunger-games.blogspot.com/) where I was trying to center the images along with their post titles, and the script I used is the one below

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
/**
this script was written by Confluent Forms LLC http://www.confluentforms.com
for the BlogXpertise website http://www.blogxpertise.com
any updates to this script will be posted to BlogXpertise
please leave this message and give credit where credit is due!
**/

$(document).ready(function() {
    // 0change the dimension variable below to be the max pixel width you want the grid elements to be
    // this works better if they're the same size
    var width       = 190;
    var height      = 190;

    // need an image to use in case the blog post does not have an image
    // works best if the image is the same dimensions as the above variable values for grid size
    var placeholder = 'http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bY-qeacmAlA/UI_98V9I9WI/AAAAAAAAGWc/8FzFSGYaj3o/s270/placeholder.jpg';

    // grid margins such as 5px
    var margins     = "15px 2px 5px 2px";

    // set 1 for squared image or 0 for proportional,
    // highly recommend squared otherwise grid might not display properly
    // squared images only works for images hosted in Picasa
    var square      = 1;

    // style info for the "alt" area where the post title will be displayed
    var altBackground       = "#000000";
    var altTextColor        = "#ffffff";
    var altPaddingTop       = 15;
    var altPaddingBottom        = 20;
    var altPaddingSides     =5; 

    var paddingString = altPaddingTop + 'px ' + altPaddingSides + 'px ' + altPaddingBottom + 'px ' + altPaddingSides + 'px';

    $('.post-body').each(function(n, wrapper){
        var wrapper         = $(wrapper);
        var image       = $(wrapper).find('img').first();
        var link        = wrapper.parent().find('h3 a');
        var linkURL         = link.attr('href');
        var linkTitle       = link.text();

        $(link).remove();
        wrapper.empty();

        if (image.attr('src')) {
            var imageOriginalHeight = image.attr('height');
            var imageOriginalWidth = image.attr('width');   
            var imageParent = $(image).parent();

            wrapper.append(imageParent);

            if (square) {
                image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{3,4}/,'s' + width + '-c')});
                image.attr('width',width).attr('height',height);
            } else {
                image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{3,4}/,'s' + width)});
                image.attr('width',width);
                var newHeight = (imageOriginalHeight/imageOriginalWidth * width).toFixed(0);
                image.attr('height',newHeight);
            }

        } else {
            var image = $('<img>').attr('src',placeholder).attr('height',height).attr('width',width);
            var imageParent = $('<a>').append(image).appendTo(wrapper);
        }

        imageParent.attr('href',linkURL).css('clear','none').css('margin-left','0').css('margin-right','0').addClass('postImage');

        var imageAlt = $('<div>').prepend(linkTitle).css('padding',paddingString).css('color',altTextColor).css('background-color',altBackground).css('opacity','0.9').css('filter','alpha(opacity=90)').css('width',width).appendTo(imageParent);  //.

        var divHeight = imageAlt.height();
        var sums = parseInt(divHeight) + parseInt(altPaddingTop) + parseInt(altPaddingBottom);
        imageAlt.css('margin-top','-'+sums+'px');           
        wrapper.css('float','left').css('height',height).css('width',width).css('margin',margins).css('overflow','hidden');
    });
    $('#blog-pager').css('clear','both');
});

function killLightbox() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; ++i) {
        images[i].onmouseover=function() {
            var html = this.parentNode.innerHTML;
            this.parentNode.innerHTML = html;
            this.onmouseover = null;
        };
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load',killLightbox,undefined);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',killLightbox);
}
//]]></script>
<style>
a.postImage div {
    display:    block;
} a.postImage:hover div {
    display:    block;
}
h3, .post-footer {
    display:    none;
}
 h2{display: none;}
</style>
```

This is the modified script the actual one you can find [here](http://pastie.org/pastes/5138398/text) To test your modifications you can use the [Stylebot app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) extension in chrome or other browsers. Many thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how to edit the script, but over the chrome console i did the following to fix it.

1. remove the float right for  under post-body.
2. offset the image itself.

The text is already centered, the problem is the positioning of the elements.

see screenshot -> boomlands

[image]

EDIT

```
     .postImage img {left: -6px; bottom: 10px;} 
     .post-body a {float:none;}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @brygiger ! I tried post image offsetting using this .postImage{left:15px; right:15px; position:absolute;} and it worked but now the right side part gets cut off ! Any suggestions on the css ?

Comment: "this"? sorry. <3chars>
edit, saw the rest of the comment. gimme a sec

Comment: try .postImage img {left: 5px; bottom: 10px;} you should be moving the img tag and not the parent for the image center.
\

Comment: Yeah it worked ! :D but the first image title gets cut off a bit ! Any solution for that ?

Comment: well, the div is too small for the text, so you either you make the containing div bigger(taller)  and wrap the text or make the text smaller.

Comment: by the way, i think you have a a bug: edit: nvm my browser -_- ok for the first image change left padding: 15px 5px 20px;

Comment: omg ! what happened ? did it happen on post pages or on homepage

Comment: uhmm, you just removed the padding style.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56729/discussion-between-brygiger-and-geniusknight).